# populate array into input box Angular

Tags: angular

I'm working on a task I'm assigned to generated 10 different input forms and create an array of 10 users and loop them to fill the input box with Angular.

So at the end of the day, I'll have 10 input forms containing the array of data

**but im getting only the last data in the array information in all the forms.**

preview here [preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMM8B.png)

**contactForm.component.html**

```
<div*ngFor="let item of info">
  <form class="form-signin form" [formGroup]="kForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)" >

    <div class="form-label-group">
      <input type="email" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" autofocus #name [(ngModel)]="item.name"  >
      <label for="inputName">Name</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-label-group">
      <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" formControlName="email"
        autofocus #email [(ngModel)]="item.email" >
      <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-label-group">
      <input type="text" id="inputPhone" class="form-control" placeholder="phone" formControlName="phone" #phone [(ngModel)]="item.phone">
      <label for="inputPhone">Phone</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-label-group">
      <input type="text" id="inputCountry" class="form-control" placeholder="country" formControlName="country"
        #country [(ngModel)]="item.country" >
      <label for="inputCountry">Country</label>
    </div> 
</div>
</div>
```

**contactForm.component.ts**

```
@Input('theData') data: Contact
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
     private contactInfo: ContactInfoService) {
    }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.kForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [null, [Validators.required]],
      email: [null, [Validators.required]],
      phone: [null, [Validators.required]],
      country: [null, [Validators.required]]
    })
    this.info= this.contactInfo.information;
   }
```

**conatct.service.ts**

```
data: any[];
constructor() { }


information = [
{
  name: "lamar",
  email: "lamar@gmail.com",
  phone: "023232349403",
  country: "USA",
},
{
  name: "John doe",
  email: "johndoe@gmail.com",
  phone: "023232349403",
  country: "canada",
},
{
  name: "sam doe",
  email: "sam@gmail.com",
  phone: "032322349403",
  country: "China",
},
{
  name: "dan doe",
  email: "dan@gmail.com",
  phone: "023232349403",
  country: "China",
},
{
  name: "anne drick",
  email: "anne@gmail.com",
  phone: "023232349403",
  country: "UK",
},
{
  name: "Vals",
  email: "vals@gmail.com",
  phone: "023232349403",
  country: "Singapore",
},
{
  name: "daniel crunch",
  email: "daniel@gmail.com",
  phone: "023232349403",
  country: "Guinea",
},
{
  name: "bevelo",
  email: "bevelo@gmail.com",
  phone: "023232349403",
  country: "indonesia",
},
{
  name: "andreas",
  email: "andreas@gmail.com",
  phone: "023232349403",
  country: "Germany",
},
{
  name: "mavis",
  email: "mavis@gmail.com",
  phone: "023232349403",
  country: "London",
},


];


  triggerMe() {
    console.log("trigger me !");
    this.data = this.information;
    console.log(this.data);
  }
```

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create any new components. What you need is a `FormArray` which contains a nested `FormGroup` for the contact fields. Check the Stackblitz I made based on your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svp7no.

The main point there is that you have to create a `FormArray` and populate it with existing data in your .ts file. I added also an example of how to add new contacts:

```
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  // this getter helps to reference the nested array so that you don't have to write every time the whole "this.kform.get...." etc
  get contacts(): FormArray {
    return <FormArray>this.kForm.get('contactsArray');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.kForm = this.fb.group({
      contactsArray: this.fb.array([])
    });
    this.info = this.information;
    this.info.forEach(contact => {
      this.addContact(contact)
    })
  }

  addContact(contact: any) {
    this.contacts.push(this.createContactGroup(contact));
  }

  addNewContact() {
    this.addContact({ name: null, email: null, phone: null, country: null});
  }

  createContactGroup(contact: any): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({  
      name: [contact.name, [Validators.required]],
      email: [contact.email, [Validators.required]],
      phone: [contact.phone, [Validators.required]],
      country: [contact.country, [Validators.required]]
    })
  }
```

Then in your template you can reference the array and the nested form group:

```
<form [formGroup]="kForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)">

  <div formArrayName="contactsArray" *ngFor="let contact of contacts.controls; let i = index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <div>
        <label for="inputName">Name: </label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" autofocus>
      </div>
```

So you almost had it already ;) Feel free to ask if you have any doubts.
BTW, you were mixing Template driven forms and ReactiveForms. My example is a ReactiveForm. I removed any innecessary references to template driven forms.

Comment: that was awesome work exactly what I wanted but I have a little problem that's if I submit a button it doesn't show the exact form content in the end console but all the other forms as well.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand. Do you want to submit only one of the contacts instead of all of them?

Comment: yes in a way to list all of them and if i submit i should only get the data of the submitted form

Comment: Add a button to submit individual contacts: `<button type="button" (click)="submitContact(contact.value)">Submit contact</button>`. I updated the Stackblitz.

Comment: F that's great and thank you so much. 
Actually I think I would need more of your assistance if you don't mind, 
this the problem I was solving but it seems i got it wrong along, kindly check if you can guide me up []( https://www.scribd.com/document/456666630/Task)  @kari

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a separate form component. Please check:
- Template-driven forms from - https://angular.io/guide/forms and using within https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms
- This articles will help you - https://coryrylan.com/blog/building-reusable-forms-in-angular and https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-form-builder-and-validation-management

After that in your main component, you will iterate by "information" data and in template will use something like this:

```
<div*ngFor="let item of info">
  <form class="form-signin form" [formGroup]="klloydForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)" >
  <profile-address-form formControlName="profile"></profile-address-form>
</div>
```

Comment: that's great but seemly I have bit understanding iterating through the profile component, do you mind explaining a bit

Comment: I'm a bit confused with the  **formControlName="profile"** in the component selector, do you mind explaining it a bit.